# MySQL parse Column to obtain a numerical section and add them up

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
+------------------+
|   ColumnName     |
+------------------+
| 1 Slap           |
+------------------+
| 13 Slap          |
+------------------+
| 2 Slap           |
+------------------+
```

With only MySQL how can I parse that ColumnName to only grab the numerical value and add them all up?

The output of the query should be 16 if doing it on the above table.

Comment: If all rows always say `n Slap` you can use an integer and add ` Slap` to it in your app. :)

Comment: What you say is true, but my curiosity lies in being able to do the requested with what is given.

Comment: Does anyone even test answers any more? lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(ColumnName as SIGNED)) FROM TableName
```

(or `UNSIGNED` if you don't have any negative numbers)

**Edit:** Test data to satisfy the skeptics.

```
mysql> select * from testtable;
+---------+
| testcol |
+---------+
| 1 Slap  |
| 13 Slap |
| 2 Slap  |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select sum(cast(testcol as unsigned)) from testtable;
+--------------------------------+
| sum(cast(testcol as unsigned)) |
+--------------------------------+
|                             16 |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Did you even test your answer? It doesn't work. The sum returns number of columns in the table, not the total of all numbers in said columns. Note that the question is specific to mysql

Comment: I tested the answer on mysql and it did indeed sum the numbers.

Comment: I'd love to see your test data. Using the OPs data, your answer returns `3`, not `15`

Comment: @awm, I appologize that I was mistaken. I'm unsure that happen as the results I posted were indeed what I was getting. Your answer was the first one I was thinking would work too when I was getting ready to answer and found that the results were not as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(LEFT(ColumnName, INSTR(ColumnName, ' ')) as SIGNED))
FROM Table
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works in mysql. However, you have a typo. `, SIGNED` should be `as SIGNED`

Comment: This is most certainly not the only answer that actually works.